# How to set the data source manually and print RDLC reports directly without report viewer control from list in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer, bindingsource

I'm trying to set the data source manually and print RDLC reports directly without report viewer control

from list in VB.NET.

below I am attaching my code may not be perfect please guide me.

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNPRINT.Click
        Dim order = OrderBusiness.GetOrder()
        Dim localReport As New LocalReport()
        localReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\Report1.rdlc"
        localReport.Print("Microsoft Print To PDF")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = OrderBusiness.GetOrder.OrderDetails()}
        TextBox1.Text = OrderBusiness.GetOrder.CustomerName()
        DATAGRIDVIEW1.DataSource = bindingSource
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Order
    Public Property CustomerName As String
    Public Property OrderDetails As List(Of OrderDetail)
End Class
Public Class OrderDetail
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property UnitPrice As Integer
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property Discount As Integer
End Class
Public Class OrderBusiness
    Public Shared Function GetOrder() As Order
        Return New Order() With {
                .CustomerName = "John Doe",
                .OrderDetails = New List(Of OrderDetail)() From {
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Foo",
                        .UnitPrice = 100,
                        .Quantity = 1,
                        .Discount = 0
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Bar",
                        .UnitPrice = 200,
                        .Quantity = 2,
                        .Discount = 50
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Baz",
                        .UnitPrice = 50,
                        .Quantity = 3,
                        .Discount = 0
                    }
                }
            }
    End Function
End Class
```

RESULT REPORT DATA DATASET

[image: RESULT REPORT DATA DATASET]

```
Public Module LocalReportExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Sub Print(ByVal report As LocalReport, ByVal printerName As String)
        Dim pageSettings = New PageSettings()
        pageSettings.PaperSize = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize
        pageSettings.Landscape = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().IsLandscape
        pageSettings.Margins = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins
        Print(report, pageSettings, printerName)
    End Sub
    <Extension()>
    Sub Print(ByVal report As LocalReport, ByVal pageSettings As PageSettings, ByVal printerName As String)
        Dim deviceInfo As String = $"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>"


    Dim warnings() As Warning
    Dim streams = New List(Of Stream)()
    Dim currentPageIndex = 0
    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo,
                  Function(name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek)
                      Dim stream = New MemoryStream()
                      streams.Add(stream)
                      Return stream
                  End Function, warnings)
    For Each stream As Stream In streams
        stream.Position = 0
    Next
    If streams Is Nothing OrElse streams.Count = 0 Then
        Throw New Exception("Error: no stream to print.")
    End If
    Dim printDocument = New PrintDocument()
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings
    If Not printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
        Throw New Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.")
    Else
        AddHandler printDocument.PrintPage,
            Sub(sender, e)
                Dim pageImage As Metafile = New Metafile(streams(currentPageIndex))
                Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                    e.PageBounds.Top - CInt(e.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)
                currentPageIndex += 1
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < streams.Count)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, adjustedRect)
            End Sub

        AddHandler printDocument.EndPrint,
            Sub(Sender, e)
                If streams IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each stream As Stream In streams
                        stream.Close()
                    Next
                    streams = Nothing
                End If
            End Sub
        printDocument.PrintController = New StandardPrintController()
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName
        printDocument.Print()
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add datasource by referencing `LocalReport.DataSources`

```
Dim reportViewer As ReportViewer = New ReportViewer()
Dim rd1 As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", [your data])
Dim rd2 As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet2", [your data])
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd1)
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd2)
reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("Image", deviceInfo,
                  Function(name, fileNameExtension, encoding, mimeType, willSeek)
                      Dim stream = New MemoryStream()
                      streams.Add(stream)
                      Return stream
                  End Function, warnings)
```

If there are no ReportViewer Control, reference `report.DataSources`

Comment: Thank you your answer but the answer is mixed with C#  program language and I make like this `Dim rd1 As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (OrderBusiness.GetOrder()))` `Dim rd2 As New ReportDataSource("DataSet2", (OrderBusiness.GetOrder.OrderDetails()))`
so I have an error `The report data source object must be of the type System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource, or System.Type.`

Comment: @siwa86 oh sorry I reused some code from C#. FYI: You can modify `GetOrder()` and convert your class to datatable for RDLC following the guide [here](https://beyondtechs.blogspot.com/2013/03/convert-object-into-datatable-c.html)